# animated auto change background images randomly

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, jquery-animate

First of all I want to ask if I can change background image with css(if not in jquery or javascript the point is to build simple code).
Well, second, I want to divide the background to three parts with different sizes and then place photo in every part(three photos) and I want every part's photo to be auto animated changed randomly after number of seconds.
For examply I have part1 part2 part3 in the background and I have image1 image2 image3 image4 image5 image6 image7 so it have to be like this(for example):

```
part1=image6
part2=image3
part3=image7
```

after 3 seconds:

```
part1=image2(the other stays as it is)
```

after 2 seconds:

```
part2=image1
part3=image4
```

after 5 seconds:

```
part3=image2
part1=image4
```

and like that.
It seems like the instagram background of photos in every user profile, yeah I want something like this.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: `like instagram profile`...assumes everyone uses instagram which is not likely. Create mockup demo of what you want this to look like in jsfiddle.net. As far as changing , is not difficult using jQuery `css()`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

might be like this if using css

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeBG {
from {background: url(image1.jpg);}
to { background: url(image2.jp);}
}
@-moz-keyframes changeBG {
from {background: url(image1.jpg);}
to {background: url(image1.jpg);}
}
```

or if you want to use more image you can use css keyframes start from 0% to 100% like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeBG {
        0% {background: url(image1.jpg);}
        10% { background: url(image2.jp);}
20% { background: url(image3.jp);}
30% { background: url(image4.jp);}
40% { background: url(image5.jp);}
50% { background: url(image6.jp);}
60% { background: url(image7.jp);}
70% { background: url(image8.jp);}
80% { background: url(image9.jp);}
90% { background: url(image10.jp);}
100% { background: url(image11.jp);}
        }
```

Comment: Nope :/ can you try it then tell me if it works for you and give me an example?